# Wordpress media library how to re-enable the Infinite Scroll functionality

Tags: wordpress, media-library

Since the WordPress v5.8, the **Infinite Scroll** for Media items has been disabled.

Instead of the infinite scroll, WordPress has introduced the Load More button.

The **Load More** button is okay when you have less media items. But I have 15000+ media items stored in my WordPress Media Library.

I love to use the infinite scroll to the Media Library and don't want to click on Load More button again and again and again.

Anyway I can get that functionality back?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new filter named media_library_infinite_scrolling.
To enable infinite scrolling in the media library again:

```
add_filter( 'media_library_infinite_scrolling', '__return_true' );
```

Read more here ( https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/media_library_infinite_scrolling/ )

Comment: Amazing! Worked like charm. Thank you @martin-mirchev